# C++ efficient way to map a group of integer variables to values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

In order to map a group of integer variables to values (*say I have `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6` to determine a value `v`;* that's a map like `map<tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int>,VALUE_TYPE>` or `map<struct{int, int, int, int, int, int},VALUE_TYPE>`), we may use

1. string constructed from integers as key
2. tuple as key
3. struct or class as key
4. and so on ...

I am very curious about the performance of these methods. In my situation,

1. less insertion, more query
2. wide range but sparse distribution of integer keys
3. time concerns me more, memory less
4. map access is the most consuming part, so even 10% speedup matters

The question is which way performs better in my situation? 
If struct or class key chosen, is there any trick to make comparator more efficient? 
Does unordered_map fit the situation better? How should I calculate hash of keys?

I will appreciate a lot to any suggestion or comment on solutions. And discussion on a more general situation is also welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Map variables to values? Just store the values in them.

Comment: A std::map can map integers to values. Why would you consider strings, tuples or custom classes? Put your integers in the map.

Comment: Key is mutiple integers, like [x, y, z] if using 3 variables to determine the value. I've edited the question to eliminate ambiguity.@nvoigt @storyteller

Comment: In your group of integer variables `(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6)` does the place of every variable `ai`matters? Is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` same as `(3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 5)`?

Comment: Order matters. @sameerkn

Comment: Possibly consider a *sorted vector* and use a *binary search* on just the first integer and only considering subsequent integers if more than one found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically: Implement the different solutions, write a performance test program and measure!

For sure:

- Using the integers as integers will be faster than converting them to strings.
- A struct (or class) should be faster than a tuple (my experience).
- Also try the `std::array<>` container (already provides operators for comparison too).
- Hash map (`std::unordered_map<>`) is faster than a sorted map (`std::map<>`), but can of course only be used if you don't need to search with partial keys.

Comment: As an addition: `std::unordered_map` may be less effective than `std::map` for long keys: comparison of two arrays for `<` typically uses just a couple of first elements while calculation of hash is much more expensive. For example, on my machine 10 000 insertions of `std::array<int, 10000>` to `std::map` are 3 times faster than to `std::unordered_map`. However, this probably isn't the case of topic starter.

Comment: Using an array for the key type is a brilliant idea, in my opinion. Even though I'm not the person asking, thank you for that.

Comment: using `std::array` will be good if the order of element inside `array` matters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I agree with using std::array as key.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider implementing the [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure if your numbers are relatively small and you have a lot of them in a key. Just like `std::unordered_map` this will allow you to access the element in `O(l)` time where `l` is a length of the key, but also it will allow you to iterate throw all the values in ascending order and find a value by a partial key. The problem here is that your memory consumption will be proportional to the alphabet size (of course, you can store the inner edges in some complex data structure, but this will negatively affect performance).